# not able to get rating of phone from amazon

Tags: python-2.7, data-cleaning

## for this code I am getting mutiple output for a phone rating but I need only output as number of reviews and its rating

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
x=[]
def rating_amazon(url):
    #url="http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Galaxy-Smartphone-Prime-SM-G610F/dp/B01LY4V6IM"
    request =  requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request,"html.parser")
    for i in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'a-size-base','id':'acrCustomerReviewText'}):
        print i.text.replace("customer ","")
    for i in soup.find_all('i', attrs={'class':'a-icon a-icon-star a-star-3'}):
        #print i.find('span', attrs={'class':'a-icon-alt'})
        print i.text

url=["http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Galaxy-Smartphone-Prime-SM-G610F/dp/B01LY4V6IM","http://www.amazon.in/SAMSUNG-Galaxy-J7-2016-White/dp/B01JEH8ND0"]
counter=0
while counter<len(url):
    rating_amazon(url[counter])
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want one result then what is the use of 2nd for loop in the `rating_amazon`.
Just store `findall` in the list and use first instance.

```
for i in soup.find_all('i', attrs={'class':'a-icon a-icon-star a-star-3'}):
    print i.text
```

Change it like this,

```
a=soup.find_all('i', attrs={'class':'a-icon a-icon-star a-star-3'})
print a[0].text
```

I got result like this,

```
47 reviews
3.2 out of 5 stars
28 reviews
3.0 out of 5 stars
```